# Calculating MAX NOFILE and MAX NPROC on Linux Servers

Tags: linux, rsyslog, open-files

Is there any formula or basis that we can consider to calculate hard and soft limits for NPROC and NOFILE? My system is currently using 4096 for NOFILE which is the default value, and we recently had an issue with rsyslog because there were too many open files.

```
rsyslogd: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': Too many open files
```

There is a way to increase the NOFILE in rsyslog to prevent this issue. However, regardless of this issue, is there a way we can use, like the amount of physical memory installed or total disk space or CPU counts, to calculate MAX NOFILE and NPROC for a system?